# Must continuous surjection $f:\Bbb Z[\frac16]\to\Bbb Z[\frac16]$, fixed in $\lvert\cdot\rvert_3$, stabilise to approach $0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, p-adic-number-theory, fixed-point-theorems

> Must a uniformly continuous (under the 2adic metric) surjection $f:\Bbb Z[\frac16]\to\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ which is fixed in $\lvert\cdot\rvert_3$, stabilise in order to approach $0$?

Let us say that some sequence generated by repeated composition of a function $S=(f^n(x):n\in\Bbb N)$, approaches $0$, then its approach *stabilises* if and only if the sequence with its powers of $2$ factored out $\overline S=(f^n(x)\lvert f^n(x)\rvert_2:n\in\Bbb N)$ is a fixed point, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline S=(\ldots,y,y,y,\ldots)$

---

Let $X=\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ with the 2-adic topology.

Let some continuous surjection $f:X\to X$ satisfy:

- $f:X\setminus0\mapsto X\setminus 0$
- $f:0\mapsto0$ (and this is the only fixed point).
- $f$ commutes with both multiplication by $2$ and multiplication by $3$, i.e. $f(2x)=2f(x)$ and $3f(x)=f(3x)$
- $f$ is strictly monotonic in its powers of $2$, i.e. $\lvert f(x)\rvert_2<\lvert x\rvert_2$, and
- $f$ is fixed in its powers of $3$, i.e. $\lvert f(x)\rvert_3=\lvert x\rvert_3$

---

By the last but one condition, clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x)=0$

It's easy to pick out trivial examples of the above, i.e. $f$ that stabilise as they approach $0$, for example $f(x)=2x$ fulfils all the above conditions and for that the required result is trivial, i.e. that $\overline S=(\ldots x,x,x)$ and therefore $S$ stabilises on approach to $0$.

---

> But is it possible to find a counterexample, or show there is no counterexample to the rule that $\overline S$ always stabilises like this as it approaches the fixed point $0$?

I'm looking hopefully at the following conditions:

- $f$ is continuous with compact support (and therefore, I think, uniformly continuous by Heine Cantor Theorem.)
- $f^n(x)\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty$
- $0$ is a fixed point
- $\overline S$ in some sense measures position orthogonal to $0$

Perhaps therefore $\overline S$ must be a fixed point in some vicinity of $0$

---

I suspect the proof looks like this:
Every $f$ having some approach to $0$ which does not stabilise, necessarily also has some approach in which the powers of $3$ vary.

Comment: A basic class of counterexamples is given by $f(x)= \color{red}{-}2^n x$, and one can construct more from these by building "piecewise" functions with different $n$ and/or choosing sometimes + and sometimes - for different $x$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thank you. Is it possible without negative numbers?

Comment: Every $x\in X$ has a unique decomposition $x = \pm \prod_{p \text{ prime}} p^{x_p}$ where $x_p \in \Bbb Z$ and $x_p \ge 0$ for $p\ge 5$. Take any surjection $id \neq a: \Bbb N_0 \rightarrow \Bbb N_0$, take your favourite prime $p' \ge 5$, and define $f(x)= \pm 2^{x_2+1}\cdot \prod_{p',2 \neq p \text{ prime}} p^{x_p} \cdot p'^{a(x_{p'})}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg does that mean $a$ is any surjection which nowhere coincides with the identity function? And the product in $f$ is taken over every prime except $p'$ and $2$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg is there a chirality concept in padics? I can strengthen this description of the Collatz conjecture with a chirality condition which i can only capture if I morph the graph from $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ to $\Bbb C$. I'll have to put some time into understanding the function you have described, even with the most favourable selections, I suspect "wiggles" in $\Bbb C$ while the Collatz function has constant chirality.

Comment: First comment second question: yes. First comment first question: if you want a counterexample just for some start value $x$, I think it suffices (but should be added to my comment) if the surjection $a$ has the property that for some $r \in \Bbb N_0$, $a^n(r)$ never becomes constant (then take $x := p'^r$).